# MapReduce job without mapper

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

This may be very basic question but still may be helpful to many newbies like me.

Can there be a MR job without mapper? Any scenario where we need to implement this and the way to do this?

Answer (score 10):

[IdentityMapper](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/lib/IdentityMapper.html) is a mapper which maps input directly to output.

Suppose you have an input which is of the format **key-value** and you don't have anything to do with this at the mapper phase, and the only thing you would like to do is to group the values based on the key and do some aggregation operation at the reducer phase on the values, you can use this mapper.

Answer (score 6):

If MapReduce programmer do not set the Mapper Class using JobConf.setMapperClass then IdentityMapper.class is used as a default value.

if you are not mentioning the mapper even then there will be one mapper running.so in any case atleast one mapper will be running.

http://www.fromdev.com/2010/12/interview-questions-hadoop-mapreduce.html

Answer (score -1):

I seen MR job without Mapper, only reduce part.  Your requirement is special.

In my opinions, I think it is not make sense in MR job without mapper.

Comment: Why not, the terasort is an example of an MR job without a mapper!?